# Query string for messages list returns inconsistent results compared to web interface

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

When I use code similar to the example code from the api documentation, the query strings which in the web interface return results don't work. This is listing messages, not retrieving them, so I don't think full vs raw helps. The scope granted is `gmail.readonly`

1. Is it possible to search on message body with this function?
2. Is there a way to search on domain name (i.e. all messages from or to *@example.com)
3. Is the search case-sensitive?

`service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, pageToken=page_token, q=query).execute()`

I use `'me'` for the user_id, and I checked that it's certainly the same email. A Query for `in:anywhere` on its own returns the full mail list.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**: The query in question is a single word like a name. Some of them sometimes work with 'name is:anywhere' but not consistently.

Comment: Can you elaborate on query strings you're using?  Is it multiple free-form full-text search terms (q="foo bar baz") or something like a structured query operators (q="in:inbox is:unread")?  If free-form terms, does it not return the same as web interface if you quote them in web UI ("foo bar baz" vs just searching: foo bar baz).

Comment: @EricDeFriez thanks for the comment, I've updated. The queries have included the example.com domain (the actual one), names from the body and fields, and 'is:anywhere'. The mails are archived in some cases, in case that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, message body is searched.
2. Try: "from:example.com OR to:example.com"
3. No, Gmail UI and API search is not case-sensitive.

Be aware that service.users().threads().list() would be more consistent with Gmail UI search assuming the user has conversations enabled which is the Gmail UI default.

in:anywhere expands the search to Trash and Spam which is not normally included. Archived messages are normally included.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got some domains working, but there is one thread for one domain that doesn't appear. It's in a particular label, could that be the problem?

Comment: thanks for all your help, I found the remaining fix through a bug fix!